# How can i use the same template file with a widget and category loop?

Tags: loop, widgets, variables

i wrote a widget and i want to use category template which is located in "themename"/template-parts/content.php".

```
<?php
// Category.php  
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'content', '' );
endwhile;
?>
```

In my widget i used $myposts=get_posts(); and i want to use this data with the content.php template for sure. But i dont know what is the proper way to pass this data.

I tried this but it didnt work.

```
<?php 
// Widget.php
$myposts = get_posts($another_array);
foreach($myposts as $post) {  
include(locate_template('template-parts/content.php')); 
}
?>
```

And my template file.

```
Post: <?php the_title(); ?>
Comment Count: <?php echo get_comments_number(); ?>
Url: <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>
```

I tried like this too. But still not working.

```
Post: <?php the_title($post->ID); ?>
Comment Count: <?php echo get_comments_number($post->ID); ?>
Url: <?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup postdata in order to set the `$post` global in order to make template tags available for this to work

```
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );

        get_template_part( 'content' );

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: global $post;  $gpost=$post; [YOUR CODE]  $post=$gpost;    If i make it like that. Is it going to be the proper way to do it right? I mean i dont want to do any mistakes about it.

Comment: Sorry for only replying now. The code in my answer should be the only code needed, the code you suggested would be unnecessary ;-)

Comment: Pieter can you take a look here? [link]http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227624