# What is best way passing variables to theme templates and using them different places like widgets?

Tags: loop, templates, performance

I have a template file at **/parts/template.php**
which contains a post listing code like,

```
echo get_the_title(); //same lines with my_render_function
```

and i am using it at **archive.php** with this lines.

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  get_template_part('template');
endwhile;
```

But now i wrote a **widget** and a **shortcode**. 
My widget and shortcode using a function called **shared_listing()**

```
function shared_listing(){
  $posts=get_posts();
  my_render_function($posts);
}

function my_render_function($posts){
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo get_the_title($post->ID); //same lines with template.php except $post->ID
  }
}
```

so, i found a solution. i removed **template.php** and changed **archive.php** to this.

```
if ( have_posts() ) : 
  my_render_function($posts);
endif;
```

Now, my archive.php, my widget and my shortcode uses the same template with my_render_function(). And i created a file called my_render_function.php and after adding the function lines i copied it into parts folder.

And i didnt use this lines at widget and shortcode and changed template to render function because i need pass $posts and some other variables too. Because of design $post_count is one of them. And without using a loop at the point where frontend codes in, it doesnt makes any sense.  and i need to make it right.  Not with hacks for sure.

```
setup_postdata( $post );
get_template_part('template');
```

So now my question;

in the begining i was using **get_the_title();** at template.php and **get_the_title($post->ID);** at widget and shortcode loop. 
but now im using get_the_title($post->ID) at all of them.

*1- is that makes my system more slower?*

*There is an object cache mechanism in wp, so it shouldnt affect, i believe.*

in the beginning i was using **get_template_part()** at archive.php with **have_posts()** and foreach render function at shortcode and widget.
now im using **include()** (only once at function.php) and **foreach render function** at all of them.

*2- is it the best way to make it right? or are there any other logical and high performance solution to do this?*

sorry for my poor english and thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 If you look at the [source code of `get_the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/#source-code) you will see that there is no difference between the two ways of writing the same thing, because if you call it without a parameter it is supposed to be the current ID.

2 There is no substantial difference between the two loops you use. All go through the same amount of items and do the same thing with it. Theoretically putting everything in `archive.php` would be a bit faster, because you skip the function call to `get_template_part()`.

In short: when it comes to performance the two options are hardly any different.

Comment: If i use classic template structure, templates will be included only when they needed.  But in my example all the templates will be included in function.php as functions, and they will be used if necessary.  I didnt understand your answer exactly.  Are you saying there is no difference between them?

Comment: Yes, I am saying there is no difference. If you use a template only once it will be in memory, because WP thinks it may be needed again. If you have it in `functions.php` it will also be in memory.

Comment: Alright then i will use my example with one simple change.  Im not going to include at function.php, i will turn each template to a function file, and i will use include_once() in widget,shortcode and archive.php files.  With that i can pass $posts or whatever i want to template functions and still performance is not gonna be an issue to me. Because in this screnerio there is no difference between get_template_part and include_once. Well it solves my question.